# Error in download.file unsupported URL scheme

Tags: json, r, web-services, ubuntu

I am working with an algorithm R that calls a webservice that makes a query to a database and returns a JSON object.

```
url <- "https://example.com?id=1"
json_file <- "C:/xampp/htdocs/example/Download/data.json"
download.file(url, json_file)
document <- fromJSON(json_file)
```

On my machine the algorithm usually works bad when I go up to the server and run, I get the following error:

```
Error in download.file(url, json_file) : unsupported URL scheme
```

here is some problem for the url be https?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Details section of `?download.file`.

> ```
>  Note that 'https://' URLs are only supported if '--internet2' or
>  environment variable 'R_WIN_INTERNET2' was set or
>  'setInternet2(TRUE)' was used (to make use of Internet Explorer
>  internals), and then only if the certificate is considered to be
>  valid.
> ```

Comment: @perondi Super User is the best place for questions like that.  See, for example, http://superuser.com/q/184625

Comment: BTW, if the anwer is useful to you, then you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow next to the tick.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, you can use `method = "curl"` to use curl to download.