# readLines() does not read from HTTPS URL when called from system("rscript")

Tags: r

When I directly call the following in RStudio, it works fine.

```
readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renkun-ken/rlist-tutorial/master/data/sample.yaml")
```

However, when I call from `rterm` or save the code to a .R file (say, `readlines.R`) and call

```
system("rscript readlines.R")
```

Then an error occurs:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: readLines -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : unsupported URL scheme
Execution halted
Warning message:
running command 'rscript readlines.R' had status 1
```

I tried a HTTP URL and there's no problem but HTTPS URL like I used always ends up in this error if the code is called from external.

How can I fix this?

My session info:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: doesn't work for me interactively (haven't tried it from a script).  Results of `sessionInfo()` from your interactive session?  Does it work if you start R with `--vanilla` ?

Comment: Use `getURL` from the `RCurl` package.

Comment: @jdharrison In fact I'm using yaml and jsonlite packages which internally calls readLines() which leads to errors when called from external.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21857323/1201032 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890633/r-produces-unsupported-url-scheme-error-when-getting-data-from-https-sites will be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @flodel, `--internet2` solves the problem! Just call `rscript --internet2 readlines.R` and it works.