# How to access to Https page in R

Tags: r

Coding in R, I am trying to parse some information from website, say, a linkedin page. The linkedin url was

url = "http://www.linkedin.com/in/lillyzhu"

I had no problem to use readLines and XML package to collect the information I need. However, that url became

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/lillyzhu"

It failed readLines function.

> readLines(url)
>   Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
>   In file(con, "r") : unsupported URL scheme

Do you know any way to read-in web information if the url is https in R? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the R package httr? Simple as:

```
library('httr')    
content(GET('https://www.linkedin.com/in/lillyzhu'))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, with this method, i only got <head> rather than <body>

Comment: Savvy, you get the content, it just truncates the response for display purposes.

Answer (score 2):

"https" is not supported by `readLines()`.  But this can easily be done with package "RCurl" to get the URL content, and package XML to parse the html text.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

content <- getURL("https://www.linkedin.com/in/lillyzhu")
doc <- htmlParse(content, asText = TRUE)

summary(doc)    
# $nameCounts
# 
#    span      div       li   script        a       br     meta        p 
#     104       92       79       77       73       22       19       14 
#    time       h5      img     link       h3       ul       h4   header 
#      14       13       13       10        9        8        7        7 
#      h2   strong       ol       td       th       tr    input noscript 
#       5        5        4        4        4        4        3        3 
#  button       dd       dt   iframe    label     body       dl       em 
#       2        2        2        2        2        1        1        1 
#    form       h1     head       hr     html    table    title 
#       1        1        1        1        1        1        1 
# 
# $numNodes
# [1] 613
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `setInternet2(TRUE)` before `readLines`.

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
web_page <- readLines("https://www.linkedin.com/in/lillyzhu")
```

See also: [Error in download.file unsupported URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857264/error-in-download-file-unsupported-url-scheme/21857323#21857323)

Comment: Smart. That is the simplest solution I have gotten so far. Many thanks.

Comment: This is only applicable to Windows users

Comment: as of R 3.3.0, setInternet2 is now defunct. So this solution is no longer feasible for R  3.3.0 or higher versions.